# What are important tips for a complete noobie regarding a layover at Mumbai via GoAir?

Tags: layovers, tips-and-tricks, bom, goair

I have researched the web about what is a layover and came to know that if flight number is different, then I have to change the plane.

*DOMESTIC FLIGHT*:

1. Do I need to worry about my checked in luggage, or is it automatically transferred to the new plane?
2. Are there proper personnel to guide for changing flight?
3. If there is only a 30 minutes window, do I need to rush or not?

Comment: `30 minutes window` You would need to run like Bolt !!

Comment: 1: No (Yes); 2: Usually; 3: It depends on the airport and on the particular flights involved.

Comment: @DumbCoder not necessarily.  I've had layovers where the departure gate was less than a five-minute walk from the arrival gate.

Comment: @phoog Supposedly if it isn't ??

Comment: @phoog Will there be any proper personnel to guide?

Comment: Proper personnel: Almost always, but I wouldn't rule out some failure of process in an exceptional case.

Comment: Where is the layover and what airline(s)?

Comment: @Johns-305 Mumbai, Go Air

Comment: @Johns-305 Do you have any important tips for me for the layover.

Comment: Can somebody here answer my 3 queries?

Comment: @DumbCoder sure, sometimes 30 minutes won't be enough, sometimes it will.  That's why I said "it depends."  The assertion that a 30-minute layover will require running is not necessarily going to be accurate in any given case.

Comment: "Can somebody here answer my 3 queries": The question is very broad as you have not specified the airport or airline (or even the country), but it seems from your comment that you have a particular airport and airline in mind.  I suggest that you edit the question to ask about the airport and airline.  Then you may get a useful answer.

Comment: @phoog see the update

Comment: @Johns-305 As far as I'm aware, Mumbai is in Asia.

Comment: Sorry, no, since my answer would only relate my experience in the US, Europe and East Asia.

Comment: @Johns-305 Do i need to worry about my checked in luggage? Yes its Asia and specifically its India.

Comment: @phoog At least tell about whether i need to again take my checked in luggage or will the checked in luggage taken care by flight personnel themselves.

Comment: @SumeetSingh I do not know whether you will have to take your checked luggage.  It depends on GoAir's business model.  Be patient; someone will answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far my knowledge, the arrival and departure gates for domestic flights in Mumbai Airport are nearby. However you will have to go through security checks again at departure gate. So, to answer your questions:

1. If both the flights are operated by same airlines (in your case GoAir) and you have a single ticket for your journey, you don't have to worry about your checked-in luggage.
2. You can get direction and information about departure gate from the flight attendants of your first flight. There will also be other security personnel to help you out. From my personal experience, they will only show you the direction and will not come and guide you. So, you will have to figure out rest on your own.
3. Ideally you should be able to make it to your next flight on a 30 minute window if you plan smartly. Inform the flight attendants of your first flight about your connection flight and ask them if you can get off first. Take your seat near the exit. Get boarding pass for both the flights before beginning of the journey and find you which get number you need to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just called the airlines and they after seeing my booking said because window is only 30 minutes, the flight will remain the same.

Comment: Is it true, that if window is this small then i do not need to change the flight.